# Mocking a class instantiated within the target class

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a Jasmine test for a function of class which instantiates and observes an object from another class. Since I want to keep this test contained to the first class and to simulate different scenarios of the second I want to mock the second. Some pseudo code might help

```
export class Foo {
    startProcessing() {
        const bar = new Bar();
        const sub = bar.tickTock.subscribe(
             state => { 
                     // something went right
                    },
             error => {
                    // something went wrong
                    }
            );
     }
}
```

I've tried declaring the mock class in my test file, and providing it through `TestBed.configureTestingModule`'s `providers` attribute, but it always uses the original Bar.
How can I write a test that provides a mock class in place of `Bar` that I can control?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this issue is to pass in object of type Bar through function parameter (dependency injection). That way you can have control over Bar object.

Comment: I have set that up, but it feels dirty to me. Because the place that calls the `startProcessing` just constructs the `new Bar()` and passes it in each time. I'd like the function to be more independent if possible.

Comment: Alternative would be to wrap statement that creates new Bar object into new function. That way you would preserve current startProcessing method signature and at the same time create a place in code from which you can control creation of Bar object via mocking that function.